# GLSL: Strange light reflections

Tags: opengl, glsl

According to [this tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-13-normal-mapping/) I'm trying to make a normal mapping using GLSL, but something is wrong and I can't find the solution. The output render is in this image:

[image]

in this image is a plane with two triangles and each of it is different illuminated (that is bad). The plane has 6 vertices. In the upper left side of this plane are 2 identical vertices (same in the lower right). Here are some vectors same for each vertice:

```
normal vector    =  0, 1, 0 (red lines on image)
tangent vector   =  0, 0,-1 (green lines on image)
bitangent vector = -1, 0, 0 (blue lines on image)
```

here I have one question: The two identical vertices does need to have the same tangent and bitangent?
I have tried to make other values to the tangents but the effect was still similar.

Here are my shaders

**Vertex shader:**

```
#version 130

// Input vertex data, different for all executions of this shader.
in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
in vec2 vertexUV;
in vec3 vertexNormal_modelspace;
in vec3 vertexTangent_modelspace;
in vec3 vertexBitangent_modelspace;

// Output data ; will be interpolated for each fragment.
out vec2 UV;
out vec3 Position_worldspace;
out vec3 EyeDirection_cameraspace;
out vec3 LightDirection_cameraspace;

out vec3 LightDirection_tangentspace;
out vec3 EyeDirection_tangentspace;

// Values that stay constant for the whole mesh.
uniform mat4 MVP;
uniform mat4 V;
uniform mat4 M;
uniform mat3 MV3x3;
uniform vec3 LightPosition_worldspace;

void main(){

    // Output position of the vertex, in clip space : MVP * position
    gl_Position =  MVP * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1);

    // Position of the vertex, in worldspace : M * position
    Position_worldspace = (M * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1)).xyz;

    // Vector that goes from the vertex to the camera, in camera space.
    // In camera space, the camera is at the origin (0,0,0).
    vec3 vertexPosition_cameraspace = ( V * M * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1)).xyz;
    EyeDirection_cameraspace = vec3(0,0,0) - vertexPosition_cameraspace;

    // Vector that goes from the vertex to the light, in camera space. M is ommited because it's identity.
    vec3 LightPosition_cameraspace = ( V * vec4(LightPosition_worldspace,1)).xyz;
    LightDirection_cameraspace = LightPosition_cameraspace + EyeDirection_cameraspace;

    // UV of the vertex. No special space for this one.
    UV = vertexUV;

    // model to camera = ModelView
    vec3 vertexTangent_cameraspace = MV3x3 * vertexTangent_modelspace;
    vec3 vertexBitangent_cameraspace = MV3x3 * vertexBitangent_modelspace;
    vec3 vertexNormal_cameraspace = MV3x3 * vertexNormal_modelspace;

    mat3 TBN = transpose(mat3(
        vertexTangent_cameraspace,
        vertexBitangent_cameraspace,
        vertexNormal_cameraspace
    )); // You can use dot products instead of building this matrix and transposing it. See References for details.

    LightDirection_tangentspace = TBN * LightDirection_cameraspace;
    EyeDirection_tangentspace =  TBN * EyeDirection_cameraspace;
}
```

**Fragment shader:**

```
#version 130

// Interpolated values from the vertex shaders
in vec2 UV;
in vec3 Position_worldspace;
in vec3 EyeDirection_cameraspace;
in vec3 LightDirection_cameraspace;

in vec3 LightDirection_tangentspace;
in vec3 EyeDirection_tangentspace;

// Ouput data
out vec3 color;

// Values that stay constant for the whole mesh.
uniform sampler2D DiffuseTextureSampler;
uniform sampler2D NormalTextureSampler;
uniform sampler2D SpecularTextureSampler;
uniform mat4 V;
uniform mat4 M;
uniform mat3 MV3x3;
uniform vec3 LightPosition_worldspace;

void main(){

    // Light emission properties
    // You probably want to put them as uniforms
    vec3 LightColor = vec3(1,1,1);
    float LightPower = 40.0;

    // Material properties
    vec3 MaterialDiffuseColor = texture2D( DiffuseTextureSampler, vec2(UV.x,-UV.y) ).rgb;
    vec3 MaterialAmbientColor = vec3(0.1,0.1,0.1) * MaterialDiffuseColor;
    //vec3 MaterialSpecularColor = texture2D( SpecularTextureSampler, UV ).rgb * 0.3;
    vec3 MaterialSpecularColor = vec3(0.5,0.5,0.5);

    // Local normal, in tangent space. V tex coordinate is inverted because normal map is in TGA (not in DDS) for better quality
    vec3 TextureNormal_tangentspace = normalize(texture2D( NormalTextureSampler, vec2(UV.x,-UV.y) ).rgb*2.0 - 1.0);

    // Distance to the light
    float distance = length( LightPosition_worldspace - Position_worldspace );

    // Normal of the computed fragment, in camera space
    vec3 n = TextureNormal_tangentspace;
    // Direction of the light (from the fragment to the light)
    vec3 l = normalize(LightDirection_tangentspace);
    // Cosine of the angle between the normal and the light direction,
    // clamped above 0
    //  - light is at the vertical of the triangle -> 1
    //  - light is perpendicular to the triangle -> 0
    //  - light is behind the triangle -> 0
    float cosTheta = clamp( dot( n,l ), 0,1 );

    // Eye vector (towards the camera)
    vec3 E = normalize(EyeDirection_tangentspace);
    // Direction in which the triangle reflects the light
    vec3 R = reflect(-l,n);
    // Cosine of the angle between the Eye vector and the Reflect vector,
    // clamped to 0
    //  - Looking into the reflection -> 1
    //  - Looking elsewhere -> < 1
    float cosAlpha = clamp( dot( E,R ), 0,1 );

    color =
        // Ambient : simulates indirect lighting
        MaterialAmbientColor +
        // Diffuse : "color" of the object
        MaterialDiffuseColor * LightColor * LightPower * cosTheta / (distance*distance) +
        // Specular : reflective highlight, like a mirror
        MaterialSpecularColor * LightColor * LightPower * pow(cosAlpha,5) / (distance*distance);


    //color.xyz = E;
    //color.xyz = LightDirection_tangentspace;
    //color.xyz = EyeDirection_tangentspace;
}
```

I have replaced the original `color` value by `EyeDirection_tangentspace` vector and then I got other strange effect but I can not link the image (not eunogh reputation)

Is it possible that with this shaders is something wrong, or maybe in other place in my code e.g with my matrices?

Comment: You should post and accept an answer, so it's clearer that this problem has been solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved... 3 days needed for changing one letter

from this:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glVertexAttribPointer
(
    4,                  // attribute. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
    3,                  // size
    GL_FLOAT,           // type
    GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
    sizeof(VboVertex),                  // stride
    (void*)(12*sizeof(float))            // array buffer offset
);
```

to this:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glVertexAttribPointer
(
    4,                  // attribute. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
    3,                  // size
    GL_FLOAT,           // type
    GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
    sizeof(VboVertex),                  // stride
    (void*)(11*sizeof(float))            // array buffer offset
);
```

see difference? :)